# Increase pixel size of a picture

Tags: c#

My project uses a lot of pictures and I need to make a preview for them.
My problem is that some of them are really small (16x16 pixels) so when I stretch them in a picturebox, it will look very blur.
I would like to be able to see the actual pixels like this (example in Paint):

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

I tried to resize it with few methods but none worked for me.

Comment: I think it is because of compression type used in your image format. if you save the 16x16 image in bmp format and stretch it and save it also in bmp format no bluring will occur.

Comment: The zoom mode of the PictureBox will always use anti-aliasing. You need to do the resizing yourself, see the link above!

Comment: Thanks TaW! :) That helped me